# Galois extension - minimum polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

Let $K$ be a Galois extension of $F$ and let $a\in K$. Let $n=[K:F]$, $r=[F(a):F]$, $G=\text{Gal}(K/F)$ and $H=\text{Gal}(K/F(a))$.

We symbolize with $\tau_1, \ldots , \tau_r$ the representatives of the left cosets of $H$ in $G$.

1. Show that $\displaystyle{\min (F,a)=\prod_{i=1}^r\left (x-\tau_i(a)\right )}$.
2. Show that $\displaystyle{\prod_{\sigma \in G}\left (x- \tau_i(a)\right )=\min (F,a)^{n/r}}$, where $\tau_i$ is the unique representative such that $\sigma \in \left[ \tau_i \right]$.

$$$$

Could you give me a hint how we could show these two points? I don't really have an idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first point, try to show that if $i \neq j$, then $\tau_i(a) \neq \tau_j(a)$.

For the second one, try to show that if $\sigma, \tau$ belong to the same class modulo $H$, then $\sigma(a) = \tau(a)$

Comment: Do I have to write a full proof?

Comment: For the first part: Do they have to be different because the number of the left costes is equal to the extension degree $[F(a):F]$ ?

Comment: Yes, since $\tau_i$ maps a root of a polynomial into a root of the same polynomial. With this claim you can show that $\tau_i(a)$ define all' the roots of $min(F,a)$, since it's degree is exactly $r$, so It must have the form you have described above

Comment: Ah ok!! Could you explain to me also further the second point?

Comment: Yes, for sure.
First show that if $\sigma,\tau$ belong to the same class modulo $H$, then $\sigma(a)=\tau(a)$;

Since $\vert G:H \vert = r$, each coset contains exacly $\frac{n}{r}$ elements.

Denote with $C_1,...,C_r$ the distinct cosets of $G$ modulo $H$., then \begin{align}
\prod_{\sigma \in G}(x-\tau_i(a)) &= \prod_{\sigma \in C_1}(x-\tau_1(a)) \cdots \prod_{\sigma \in C_r}(x-\tau_r(a)) \\ &= (x-\tau_1(a))^{n/r} \cdots (x-\tau_r(a))^{n/r} \\  &= (\prod_{1}^r(x-\tau_i(a)) )^{n/r} \\ &= min(F,a)^{n/r}
\end{align}

Hope it's clear.

Comment: Ah ok!! Thank you so much!! :-)